# can we use json file as datatable in karate?

Tags: karate

I'm trying to make datatable values dynamic using json file.

Can anybody help with dynamic datatable creation? I want to get the datatable values from json file.

Here is my code:

```
Scenario Outline: get all users and then get the first user by id

Given path 'users'

And request read('request.json')

When method post

Then status 201

Examples:
| kittens |
```

And:  Kittens.json

```
{
    "id" : "11"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the docs carefully, and there are examples: https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline

Change `kittens.json` to the below (note that it has to be a JSON array, see the square brackets):

```
[{ id: 11 }]
```

And then this should work:

```
Examples:
| read('kittens.json') |
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter its working for me. Can you please explain how to use csv file to dynamic datatables with example.

Comment: @Shubham you should be able to figure this out from the documentation. see here:  https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/outline/dynamic-csv.feature